# Асинхронные запросы к sqlite3 базе данных

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность, sqlite

Есть сервер онлайн игры к которому я хочу прикрутить простую статистику, бд решил использовать sqlite3.
Проблема в том что делать запросы синхронно на сервере в главном потоке не позволительно, а асинхронного API если я не ошибаюсь sqlite не имеет.
Я предполагаю что нужно создать поток, а в нем очередь и посылать потоку запросы из основного потока сервера которые он будет выполнять соблюдая очередь и вызывать callback функции.
Так ли это делается? Если да то как такое можно реализовать?
Многипоточные приложения я не когда не писал и умею делать только самые простые операции с потоками, а вот как в поток что-то "передать" понятия не имею.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Речь о "передаче чего-то в поток", или об организации совместного доступа к разделяемым ресурсам?

Comment: Наверно первое, мне нужно передать в поток sql запрос, небольшую порцию данных и каллбек функцию чтоб оно выполнилась после выполнения запроса

Comment: Похоже, что Вы пытаетесь реализовать классический алгоритм Consumer-Producer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несколько часов изучения STL и C++ и я смог реализовать это ;)

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>

typedef struct {
    const char *sql;
    // etc...
} query_t;

int main()
{
    std::queue<query_t> requests;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::mutex notify;

    notify.lock();


    std::thread db_async_worker([&]() {
    std::queue<query_t> temp;

        while (true) {
            mtx.lock();
            if (!requests.empty()) {
                temp = requests;
                while (!requests.empty())
                    requests.pop();
            }
            mtx.unlock();

            while (!temp.empty()) {
                std::cout << "execing db query " << temp.front().sql << '\n';
                // sqlite3_exec()
                // ...

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3)); // simulate slow query
                temp.pop();
            }
            notify.lock();
        }
    });

    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << "add sql query to db queue" << '\n';
        mtx.lock();
        requests.push({"UPDATE INTO ..."});
        mtx.unlock();
        notify.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html пункт 3

Answer (score 1):

В С++11 есть можно делать асинхронные вызовы, используя `std::async`. [Здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/launch/) приведен небольшой пример. Можно подставить и лябду вместо обычной функции. Реализуется все довольно просто, но единственный минус - отдельный поток на каждый вызов. Хотя, если запросы к базе данных не тяжелые, то вполне вероятно, что много потоков и не будет создаваться.

Comment: Запросов на изменение не много. Но достаточно, поэтому не подходит

Comment: @Виталий Вопрос не в количестве запросов, а в их "тяжести". Запросов может быть очень много, но если они будут быстро выполняться, то к моменту начала следующего запроса (создания потока), предыдущий запрос может быть уже выполнен (и поток будет закрыт). Если сделать один отдельный поток, в который Вы будете ставить эти запросы на выполнение, то по итогу получите почти то же самое, чего стараетесь избежать. В этом втором потоке будут точно такие же проблемы из-за одного "тяжелого" запроса, как и в основном потоке.

Comment: Запросы простые(обычные update). Позволить создавать поток под каждый запрос я себе не могу позволить скорее идеологически из-за того что остальной код написан как можно производительнее и если я туда буду добавлять по чучуть такого не совсем оптимального кода то сервер превратится в черепаху